# Restricting TextInput to email characters only

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.6

Using Flex SDK 4.6, I'm trying to restrict a TextInput field to email characters only as follows:

```
textInput.restrict = "a-z A-z 0-9 \- _ @ .";
```

However when I run my application, the TextInput field accepts any character. I'm really not sure why this is not working and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try these links. This might be helpful

http://www.oreillynet.com/pub/a/flex/excerpts/flex-4-cookbook/validation-formatting-regular-expressions.html

http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/08/29/validating-email-addresses-using-the-emailvalidator-class-in-flex/

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/validators/EmailValidator.html

Answer (score 2):

What if you lose the spaces in the "restrict" property? You can check in the Flex code on the internal code of the restrict property setter function and then it might help you get to the solution (don't have time to look now)

Answer (score 0):

Hi there in case you haven't solved it ...
For me the most efficient solution... cause it's minimal and doesn't even allow the false input to arrive!

.restrict = "a-z A-z 0-9 \\-\\ _ @ .";

// copy and paste 100% working as3 email restrict only allows underscore minus dot and at besides number and letters.

Comment: Easy1 ... only the accepting "-" was a bit (Syntax) Trycky !